# Dont resolve promise until after images load

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, base64

**The below is supposed:**

- loop through a group of `img` tags
- grab each tag's `src` url
- convert it to a `base64` encoded string using a `HTML 5` `canvas`
- once all images have been converted, the promise should be resolved and the callback called

**My problem:**

- I need to wait for each image to load in the `canvas` before I can  convert it to `base64`
- to solve this I used  `img.onload = function(){ ..... return base64Img; };
- Unfortunately, calling `img.src = element.src;` each time through resolves the promise, it doesn't wait for the images to load and call `return base64Img;` so I end up with an empty array when `$.when.apply($, promises).then(function(){});` is called.

**How can I change this promise so that it does not resolve until all the images have been loaded and converted?**

```
 function accountCreation(){
    $('#container').hide(); // hide the display while we save the info as it will take a few seconds, you should do a loading bar or something here instead
    var user = Parse.User.current(); // get the currently logged in user object

    // loop through each image element
    var promises = $('.images').map(function(index, element) {
          var src = $(element).attr('src');
          var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
          var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
          var img = new Image;
          img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
          img.onload = function(){
              canvas.height = img.height;
              canvas.width = img.width;
              ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
              var base64Img = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
              // Clean up
              canvas = null; 
              return base64Img;
          };
          img.src = element.src;
    });
    $.when.apply($, promises).then(function() {
        // arguments[0][0] is first result
        // arguments[1][0] is second result and so on
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            var file = new Parse.File("photo.jpg", { base64: arguments[i]}); // this part actually saves the image file to parse
            user.set("image" + i, file); // set this image to the corosponding column on our object 
        }
        // save the user object
        user.save(null,{
          success: function(user) { 
                  $('#message').html('Profile Updated!');
                  $('#container').show(); // show the screen again, you should just remove your loading bar now if you used one
          },
          error: function(user, error) {
                  console.log('Failed to create new object, with error code: ' + error.message);
          }
        });
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array of promises just contains undefined values, as the callback function doesn't return anything. As there are no `Deferred` objects in the array, the `when` method doesn't have anything to wait for, so it runs the `then` callback right away.

Create a `Deferred` object to return, and resolve it when the image is loaded:

```
var promises = $('.images').map(function(index, element) {
    // created a Deferred object to return
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    var src = $(element).attr('src');
    var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var img = new Image;
    img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
    img.onload = function(){
        canvas.height = img.height;
        canvas.width = img.width;
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
        var base64Img = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        // Clean up
        canvas = null;
        // Resolve the Deferred object when image is ready
        deferred.resolve(base64Img);
    };
    img.src = element.src;
    // return the Deferred object so that it ends up in the array
    return deferred;
});
```

Comment: Slightly better general practice to do `return deferred.promise();` instead of `return deferred;` so the resolving of the deferred is protected and can't be messed with.

Comment: Needs a `get()` to convert the jQuery object to native array